# Issue adding HTML tables into PHP Mail script

Tags: php, html, email

I have the following mail script with the structure shown below:

```
<?php
$to = 'example@testing';
$subject = 'Testing';
$from = 'test@email.com';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Create email headers
$headers .= 'From: '.$from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

// Compose a simple HTML email message
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<h1 style="color:#f40;">Hi!</h1>';
$message .= '<p style="color:#080;font-size:18px;">This is a test.</p>';
$message .= '</body></html>';

// Sending email
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo 'Your mail has been sent successfully.';
} else{
    echo 'Unable to send email. Please try again.';
}
?>
```

I then would like to put the following table inside the body as well but when adding the following, the PHP does not work:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            tr.header
            {
                font-weight:bold;
            }
            tr.alt
            {
                background-color: #777777;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
               $('.striped tr:even').addClass('alt');
            });
        </script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

            $server = mysql_connect("localhost","root", "");
            $db =  mysql_select_db("MyDatabase",$server);
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT first_name, last_name, sign_date FROM Table1 WHERE sign_date = NOW()");
        ?>
        <table class="striped">
            <tr class="header">
                <td>first_name</td>
                <td>last_name</td>
                <td>sign_date</td>
            </tr>
            <?php
               while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                   echo "<tr>";
                   echo "<td>".$row[first_name]."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$row[last_name]."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$row[sign_date]."</td>";
                   echo "</tr>";
               }

            ?>
        </table>

                <?php

            $server = mysql_connect("localhost","root", "");
            $db =  mysql_select_db("MyDatabase",$server);
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT employee_id, job_title, address FROM Table1 WHERE sign_date = NOW()");
        ?>
        <table class="striped">
            <tr class="header">
                <td>employee_id</td>
                <td>job_title</td>
                <td>address</td>
            </tr>
            <?php
               while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                   echo "<tr>";
                   echo "<td>".$row[employee_id]."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$row[job_title]."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$row[address]."</td>";
                   echo "</tr>";
               }

            ?>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

How can the two simply be added together. The PHP does not seem to be read and is ignored when combining the two, what is the most effective way of having the two scripts work together?

Comment: Show us what __exactly__ _“but when adding the following”_ looks like then.

Comment: Is it possible to add that entire table HTML script with its formatting and PHP into the PHP email function

Comment: **Side note:** Adding javascript to send in email won't help. They are stripped off anyway to avoid XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can likely combine the two parts like this - the PHP code needs to run before the mail is sent ( I found the `"but when adding the following, the PHP does not work"` a little confusing )

```
<?php

    $server = mysql_connect("localhost","root", "");
    $db =  mysql_select_db("MyDatabase",$server);


    $to = 'example@testing';
    $subject = 'Testing';
    $from = 'test@email.com';

    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // Create email headers
    $headers .= 'From: '.$from."\r\n".
        'Reply-To: '.$from."\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


    $message="
        <html>
            <head>
            <title></title>
            <style>
                tr.header { font-weight:bold; }
                tr.alt { background-color: #777777; }
                tr:nth-of-type(even) td{background-color:#777777}
            </style>
            </head>
        <body>
            <table class='striped'>
                <tr class='header'>
                    <td>first_name</td>
                    <td>last_name</td>
                    <td>sign_date</td>
                </tr>";


    $query = mysql_query('SELECT first_name, last_name, sign_date FROM Table1 WHERE sign_date = NOW()');
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $query ) ) {
        $message.='
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$row['first_name'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['last_name'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['sign_date'].'</td>
                </tr>';
    }

    $message.="
            </table>

            <table class='striped'>
                <tr class='header'>
                    <td>employee_id</td>
                    <td>job_title</td>
                    <td>address</td>
                </tr>";


        $query = mysql_query('SELECT employee_id, job_title, address FROM Table1 WHERE sign_date = NOW()');
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $message.='
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$row[employee_id].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row[job_title].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row[address].'</td>
                </tr>';
        }


    $message.="
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
    ";



    // Sending email
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
        echo 'Your mail has been sent successfully.';
    } else{
        echo 'Unable to send email. Please try again.';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Is there a way to restrict how wide the table is? Currently it trys to conform to the width of each device and it looks a bit warped if the screen is too small.

Comment: you can set an explicit width - or get fancy with the css to make it size according to screen size.

Comment: Can I use any send email in the script, does it matter what it says?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with that last comment, sorry! Please explain.

Comment: Does it matter what this says? $from = 'test@email.com';

Comment: the message should be sent OK but not good practise to use a fake sender email - for testing ok though

Answer (score 0):

When you add the HTML to the body it becomes a string.
A string can convert php variables to strings. But can't execute php code.
You'll have to execute the PHP code in advance. Add the data from the PHP code to the HTML and then add the HTML to the message body.

EDIT:

This is an example of how it would work:

```
<?php

$html = generateHTML();

$to = 'example@testing';
$subject = 'Testing';
$from = 'test@email.com';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Create email headers
$headers .= 'From: '.$from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

// Compose a simple HTML email message
$message = $html;


// Sending email
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo 'Your mail has been sent successfully.';
} else{
    echo 'Unable to send email. Please try again.';
}

function generateHTML(){
    $html = '<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><style type="text/css">tr.header{font-weight:bold;}tr.alt{background-color: #777777;}</style><script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$(".striped tr:even").addClass("alt");});</script><title></title></head><body><table class="striped"><tr class="header"><td>first_name</td><td>last_name</td><td>sign_date</td></tr>';

    $server = mysql_connect("localhost","root", "");
            $db =  mysql_select_db("MyDatabase",$server);
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT first_name, last_name, sign_date FROM Table1 WHERE sign_date = NOW()");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $html.="<tr>";
        $html.="<td>".$row[first_name]."</td>";
        $html.="<td>".$row[last_name]."</td>";
        $html.="<td>".$row[sign_date]."</td>";
        $html.="</tr>";
    }

$html.='</table><table class="striped"><tr class="header"><td>employee_id</td>td>job_title</td><td>address</td></tr>';

$server = mysql_connect("localhost","root", "");
            $db =  mysql_select_db("MyDatabase",$server);
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT employee_id, job_title, address FROM Table1 WHERE sign_date = NOW()");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $html.="<tr>";
    $html.="<td>".$row[employee_id]."</td>";
    $html.="<td>".$row[job_title]."</td>";
    $html.="<td>".$row[address]."</td>";
    $html.="</tr>";
}
$html.= '</table></body></html>';
return $html;
}
?>
```

Comment: I seem to be getting the error "Unexpected T_PRIVATE" on line: `private function generateHTML(){`

Comment: Sorry, forgot we're not in a class context. It's just function, not private function. Edited.